# How to find the first available value in a table in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

In SQL Server 2008 I find the first available slot in a table with the following stored procedure.

```
If Exists ( Select *  From Methods  Where MethodSerno =1 )  
   Select @SlotCode = Min(MethodSerno) + 1  
   From Methods  
   Where MethodSerno + 1 Not In ( Select MethodSerno  From Methods )
```

Is there an equivalent way in MS Access?

Thanks in adavance...

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish? Once we know that I am sure someone will be able to provide you with an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a table named [Methods] containing rows

```
MethodSerno
-----------
          1
          2
          4
          5
          8
         10
```

we can start with a query to find each value that does *not* have an immediate successor (n+1)

```sql
SELECT t1.MethodSerno
FROM 
    Methods t1 
    LEFT JOIN
    Methods t2
        ON t1.MethodSerno + 1 = t2.MethodSerno
WHERE t2.MethodSerno IS NULL
```

returning

```
MethodSerno
-----------
          2
          5
          8
         10
```

The "first available" value will simply be `(the smallest of those values)+1`

```sql
SELECT MIN(t1.MethodSerno) + 1 AS NextSerno
FROM 
    Methods t1 
    LEFT JOIN
    Methods t2
        ON t1.MethodSerno + 1 = t2.MethodSerno
WHERE t2.MethodSerno IS NULL
```

returning

```
NextSerno
---------
        3
```

Comment: Gord thank you for your reply. When I ran the first part of your query Access promted for the parameter value of t1.MethodSerno

Comment: Those queries work for me. Check your SQL statement; you may have a typo.

Comment: It worked fine thanks. There was a typo in my original question that was copied across